# CQ5.6 Geometrix view and edit profile URL lets view another user's details

Tags: adobe, aem

We are using the view and edit profile functionality from Geometrix on our site.

One user who is logged in can click on "my profile" link which generates following URL:

**http:///home/users/a/*user1*/profile.form.html/content/en-US/account/viewprofile**

User gets to view his profile

now if in the same user login session user edits the URL in the browser to

**http:///home/users/a/*user2*/profile.form.html/content/en-US/account/viewprofile**

He can still view another users profile information.

Which should not be the case, How do we prevent this.

Also in the first place the URL with user node should not be visisble to end user, can we do any mapping to hide this(may be on webserver level). any help on is greatly welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,